# Parsing data with Decodeable swift 4.0 not reading data - Xcode

Tags: ios, json, xcode, parsing, swift4

Im trying to parse data with JSONDecoder, however I keep getting an error. I am unsure why? If anyone could have a look at the code and explain whats going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
struct Stops1 : Decodable{
let StopName : String
let StopLat : String
let StopLon: String
}


 let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "newStops", ofType: "json")
 let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let Stops = try JSONDecoder().decode([Stops1].self, from: data)
        print(Stops)

    }
    catch let jsonErr {
        print("Error occured during Parsing", jsonErr)
    }
```

below is the local json file called "newStops" :

```
  {
  "Stops1" : {

    {
        "StopName": "loc 1",
        "StopLat": "-46.450364",
        "StopLon": "169.659519"
    },
    {
        "StopName": "loc 2",
        "StopLat": "-45.898395",
        "StopLon": "170.486386"
    },
    {
        "StopName": "loc 3",
        "StopLat": "-36.635997",
        "StopLon": "174.747697"
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is invalid.

I guess the value for key `Stops1` is supposed to be an array, then the JSON must be

```
{
 "Stops1" : [ {...},  {...},  {...} ] 
}
```

Some general thoughts about the JSON and the associated struct

- According to the naming convention it's recommended to name the keys lowercased
- The name of the struct should be in singular form (`Stop`)
- To include the name of the struct also in the properties runs contrary to the naming philosophy of Swift.

I recommend this simple form of the JSON

```
{
    "stops" : [
        {"name": "loc 1", "lat": "-46.450364", "lon": "169.659519"},
        {"name": "loc 2", "lat": "-45.898395", "lon": "170.486386"},
        {"name": "loc 3", "lat": "-36.635997", "lon": "174.747697"}
    ]
}
```

and the associated struct

```
struct Stop : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let lat : String
    let lon: String
}
```

The root object is a dictionary with key `stops`, this requires an extra umbrella struct:

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let stops : [Stop]
}
```

Now decode the JSON

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "newStops", withExtension: "json")!

do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    for stop in root.stops {
       print(stop.name)
    }
}
catch {
    print("Error occured during Parsing", error)
}
```

Comment: How can I call all ''name" values with this method?

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! :)